# Running multiple Skype clients on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, skype, macos-sierra

I'm running Mac OS X version 10.12.6.

I have three Skype accounts.To run Skype for a particular account, I was using this command:

`open -na /Applications/Skype.app --args -DataPath /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Application\ Support/Skype2`

But since the update to Skype version 8.12.0.2, this command does not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

`open -na /Applications/Skype.app --args -DataPath /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Application\ Support/Skype2 --secondary`

Comment: It might be really helpful to say what the command does and how its better than what OP suggested.

Answer (score -2):

Use different user accounts?
If you only need two, you can use Skype for Web and you could use Parallels Desktop to bring a Windows version. But don't buy Parallels Desktop just for that, it's only if you already have it.
But I would strongly suggest three different user accounts to avoid confusion.